# How does ORDER BY ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have stumbled upon a random code ID generator and I can't figure out how it works.

```
SELECT TOP (5) c1
FROM
  (
VALUES
  ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G'),
  ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7'), ('8'), ('9')
  ) AS T1(c1)
ORDER BY ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

I have looked at the following:

- select NEWID() -> E8E142CC-A918-4776-AA99-2D33DC80FE28
- select CHECKSUM('E8E142CC-A918-4776-AA99-2D33DC80FE28') -> -2089106226
- select ABS(-2089106226)  -> 2089106226

If I then try and do an "Order by 2089106226" it obviously fails

So what is "ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))" returning and what is this type of ordering called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `ORDER BY` clause doesn't have to sort on a specific column as you've discovered, but rather it can contain  any arbitrary expression. I don't believe there is any special name for this, it's just a dynamic value in the `order_by_expression` part of the `ORDER BY` [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

A non-column expression in the  `ORDER BY` might be something like

```
ORDER BY a_column % 5
```

to sort rows based on a column's value modulus 5, or like

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(a_column, 1) = 'Z' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, a_column ASC
```

to force all the values in `column` beginning with `Z`  to sort ahead of all others, but otherwise be alphabetical, by ascribing a `0` to `Z` rows and `1` otherwise (where zero sorts ahead of one).

In this case, the expression is a common method of randomizing row order in T-SQL:

```
ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
```

The `NEWID()` function will be called for each row returned by the `SELECT` statement, which results in 5 separate GUID values.  From there, each of those 5 is [passed to `CHECKSUM()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) which returns an index hash value which happens to be an integer.  `ABS()` finally forces it to be a positive integer.

So the values that are sent ultimately to `ORDER BY` is just a list of integers derived from multiple calls to `NEWID()`, and `ORDER BY` has no problem sorting integers. In the end it isn't really different from sorting a column of integer values - it's just that these are generated at query time.

If you run [this demonstration on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/953dc/2) a few times, you'll get a different sort order for the otherwise incrementing `id` on each execution. So it looks like the reason the author of the random code generator SQL in question used that `ORDER BY` is to shuffle a random set of 5 characters chosen from the `VALUES ()` list.  If you [run the code generator SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/953dc/3) and comment out the `ORDER BY`, it will always return the rowset `A,B,C,D,E`. With the `ORDER BY` in place, it returns a randomized set.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort in answering this question. It was the order at query time order that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

but from the syntax I can't see how it would work

```
ORDER BY order_by_expression
[ COLLATE collation_name ] 
[ ASC | DESC ] 
[ ,...n ] 
[ <offset_fetch> ]


<offset_fetch> ::=
{ 
    OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }
    [
      FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY
    ]
}
```